# Configuring mouse speed after Ubuntu 20.04.1 desktop installation

Tags: 20.04, touchpad

I just installed Ubuntu 20 on my parallels virtual machine and I noticed that the mouse speed is extremely fast. How can I change this/decrease the speed?

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu has both releases using *yy* format (specialist *snap* only releases intended for devices, cloud use etc) and standard *yy.mm* releases used by Desktop & Server releases. You mention both a *yy* release (Ubuntu 20 where there is no such release, closest being Ubuntu Core 20) in description, but have tagged a 20.04 desktop or server release which is a different product.  Please be specific, as *yy* releases are different products to those using format *yy.mm*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is via "Settings". Here's how you do it:

0. Press <kbd>Super</kbd> and type "settings" (or some part thereof):

   [image: Application Search]
1. Open "Settings"
2. Click on "Mouse & Touchpad" on the left-column:

   [image: Settings - Mouse & Touchpad]
3. Move the "Mouse Speed" slider to a value that works better for you

That's all there is to it. The change takes effect immediately.

Comment: I don't see trackpad options. `lsusb` report device as: PARALLELS Virtual Mouse